# method comparison/agreement - is Bland-Altman or equivalence of the mean best

Tags: agreement-statistics, method-comparison, bland-altman-plot

I am interested in the appropriate technique for assessing the agreement of the paired values of measurements made by 2 measuring devices, an equivalence test of the mean of the difference in the pairs or a Bland Altman analysis looking at if limits of agreement (ie the sample mean of the paired differences +/- 1.96 SD) lie within certain equivalence bounds so 95% of differences re acceptable.

I would have thought equivalence of the mean, eg using CIs of the differences in pairs, was less appropriate as the measuring devices might well measure the same on average but one measures low when the other measures high and vice versa so they don't agree at all. I agree this is an extreme example but even so we can have poor agreement of the paired values but overall equal means. In such a case the SD of the differences would be high but with a big enough sample size equivalence of means can be shown.
Yet I have seen equivalence of the mean suggested eg by cross-validated and chatgpt

Answer (score 1):

Both the Bland-Altman plot and the equivalence test for means do punish for high variation. If the variance is high when using an equivalence test, the resulting 95% CI will more likely not lie in between the lower and upper equivalence limit.

The important thing with both methods is that you specify these equivalence limit (or the clinical limit of agreement in the case of Bland-Altman) a priori.

They can both be used complementary to each other, since one uses a plot to asses the agreement, while the other uses a significance test. If both point you into the same direction, you have more reason to be sure of your conclusion.

Comment: thanks Mathemagician777, all good thoughts It seems the equivalence test for means is an easier test to pass. As you say it does punish for high variation but if the average difference is zero (or close to it) then with a big enough sample you can get the CI within the equivalence limit.

Comment: But with Bland Altman is it not possible that no matter how big the sample size we may never show agreement as even with a true difference of zero the methods may not agree ie too many are outside the LoA (which is not sample size dependent in that it won't get smaller with sample size like a CI, it'll just be more precisely estimated) - eg the LoAs might be wider than the required "tolerability bounds" - though we can make the LoAs less stringent if we're happy with say 50% of our pairs being too far apart rather than being strict and saying only 5% can be too far apart is the limit.

Comment: sorry Mathemagician I just saw you said this "They can both be used complementary to each other, since one uses a plot to asses the agreement, while the other uses a significance test."  its true BA has useful plots but there is also a formal "test" ie checking that the "outer" CIs of the LoAs fall inside the "tolerance limits" ie the limits we'd want the 2 measures to agree by - thanks again

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how only a very big sample size can change the fact that your CI will fall into your equivalence limit. I think it is also important to set a useful equivalence limit a priori, depending on your sample size. If I have two samples with 10 000 observations, whereas one sample has values between 100 and 200 and the other between 140 and 160, the standard deviation on the differences will still be large, compared to the big sample size we have, and your equivalence limit should then be specified accordingly that it would reject the hypothesis of agreement, no?

Comment: thanks good to have your comments, I was imagining a situation with paired data ie n "individuals" each with their (say) heart rate measured on each of 2 devices. So we can assess agreement by the difference in the paired values (pulse 72 on 1 vs 81 on the other) - so my SD is the SD of the differences. If the devices measure the same on average eg 70 but often one measures 90 when the other measures 60 then they don't agree but we can make the CI of the difference as tight as we like with a big enough sample (of paired values). We can make it smaller than the equivalence margin

Comment: I'd imagine that margin being set mainly on clinical grounds eg we'd like the new device to have a heart rate within 10 of the standard device 95% of the time. If its simply the case that for 50% of our individuals the difference is >10 then we can never have that no matter what sample size we have. The limits of agreement (LoA) are the limits enclosing 95% of the differences so we'd want the LoAs within the equivalence margins and that may not be possible.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment... Why do you want your LoA to be in your equivalence margins? The LoA is just the way of specifying 'close enough' in your Bland-Altman plot, whereas the equivalence margin does this in your equivalence test, right? Also, yes, with very big samples, your CI's will be smaller , but your variation still needs to be small as well. 'Just' increasing the sample size won't always do the trick. If your measures do differ, increasing the sample size might also increase the variance along with the sample size and this might still give big enough CI's

Comment: I think it is important to note that although a bigger sample size will give your more precise results, if your difference is big enough (and far away from 0), it should be outside the equivalence margins.

Comment: thanks again, I'd like to know the LoA ie the differences for most people re small enough ie within an acceptable clinical margin this site https://www.medcalc.org/manual/bland-altman-plot.php has a plot half way down wher its calls that the maximum allowed difference.

Comment: yes a bigger sample size will be better ... if the mean difference is big enough it will be outside the equivalence margins. I guess the difference between the CIs of the mean and the Bland Altman/LoAs approaches comes in when the mean IS within the equivalence margins (aka max allowed difference) then if the SD of those differences is large we'd never have the LoAs within the equivalence margin (even if the mean is) no matter what the sample size

Comment: oh sorry read your first email - I don't think the LoAs are any analogue to the equivalence margin. The equivalence margin in either CIs of the mean and the Bland Altman/LoAs approach is a prespecified (on clinical grounds) max tolerable/allowed difference. The LoA is maybe the analogue to the CI of the mean (they are data dependent and we'd lke them within the equivalence margin) but the CI will get smaller with sample size and the LoA won't. But the LoAs tell you what you want to know - how close the measure (on someone) of the new device is to that of the standard device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152307/discussion-between-mathemagician777-and-user3156942).